# Update table view numbering when new row is inserted

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a simple table view where the cells have a number label, and they are numbered according to their row number. This all works fine, until I try to insert a new row **at the top**.

I need a way to update all the cells below, so that the numbering is correct. Reloading the `tableview` works, however it cuts off the row insertion animation. Anyone know a solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `indexPathsForVisibleRows` to retrieve the rows that are visible, you can then loop through the returned array, use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to retrieve the corresponding cell and update the row number in its label. You could also try `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows(), withRowAnimation:.None)` but this may also interrupt the animation

Answer (score 0):

if you set up the cellForRowAt index function correctly where each label number is derived from indexpath.row then after then insert occurs just call

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Whoops sorry didn't see that. Yes I've faced this problem before too and you can try to play with the reloadSections method but I don't think I ever had any luck with that. So instead I think I ended up setting a timer to go off after the insert animation (maybe 0.3 seconds) and then reloaded the table view. Not pretty but it worked

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use this solution *(**Swift 3.0**)*:

```
CATransaction.begin()
tableView.beginUpdates()

CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { () -> Void in
    // this is supposed to be done after insertion animation    
    self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet([0]), with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
}
self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)

tableView.endUpdates()
CATransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Reload your table after row insertion completes, as work around below code may help:

```
[CATransaction begin];

[tableView beginUpdates];


[CATransaction setCompletionBlock: ^{

     //Reload your tableView here

}];

[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: indexPaths
                 withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];


[tableView endUpdates];

[CATransaction commit];
```